# Sampling distribution for mean difference from two independent Bernoulli populations

Tags: statistics, sampling

Let's assume that we have two independent Bernoulli populations,$Ber(\theta_1)$ $Ber(\theta_2)$

How do we prove that $\frac{(\bar X_1-\bar X_2)-(\theta_1-\theta_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\theta_1(1-\theta_1)}{n_1}+\frac{\theta_2(1-\theta_2)}{n_2}}}\rightarrow^d N(0,1)$?

Assume that $n_1\neq n_2$

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.:I've also posted this in CrossValidated, but since it got no answer, I've decided to also post it here.

Comment: This is a direct application of the central limit theorem.

Comment: @nicomezi I've also thought about that, but I don't think the conclusion follows, even though the conditions are true...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we have $n$ random variables of each distribution, then define
$$
\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2 =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{1i}-X_{2i})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i,
$$
where $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are iid r.v with $\mathbb{E}Y_i = \theta_1-\theta_2 $ and 
$$
Var(Y_i)=\frac{1}{n}\left(\theta_1(1-\theta_1)+\theta_2(1-\theta_2)\right).
$$ 
Now you can easily apply the CLT.

If $n_1 \neq n_2$, define 
then for large enough $n_i$ 
$$
\bar{X}_i \sim^{approx.} N(\theta_i, \frac{\theta_i(1 - \theta_i)}{n}),
$$
thus you can use the fact that difference of two normal r.v is normal with the desired parameters. 
For more rigorous treatment you have to define $\bar{X}_1 - \bar{X}_2$ for every $(n_1, n_2)$ and then take both $n_1$ and $n_2$ to $\infty$.

---

For $n_1 \neq n_2$ note that strictly from CLT (or, in particular, Laplace-De Moivre theorem) for $n_i \to \infty$ you get that
$$
\sqrt{n_i}(\bar{X}_{n_i} - \theta_i) \xrightarrow{D} \theta_i(1-\theta_i)Z, \quad i\in\{1,2\},
$$
hence, 
$$
\sqrt{n_1}(\bar{X}_{n_1} - \theta_1) - \sqrt{n_2}(\bar{X}_{n_2} - \theta_2) \xrightarrow{D} \theta_1(1-\theta_1)Z - \theta_2(1-\theta_2)Z = Z(0, \theta_1(1-\theta_1) + \theta_2(1-\theta_2) ),
$$
now, note that weak convergence holds for $n_1 \to \infty$ and $n_2\to \infty$. thus starting at some $N \in \mathbb{R}$, you can state that $n_1 \approx n_2 =n$, when you get 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n} ( (\bar{X}_{n_1} - \bar{X}_{n_2}) - (\theta_1 - \theta_2) )}{\sqrt{\theta_1(1-\theta_1) + \theta_2(1-\theta_2)}} \xrightarrow{D} N(0,1).
$$
For any finite $n_i$ the distribution is only approximately normal. For non "large enough" $n_i$ and imbalanced design the approximation is not that good. For analysis of goodness of this approximation for small $n_i$s, you need to do much more neat analysis and not the asymptotic arguments that I've used.

EDIT:

To be precise with the requirements for $n_1$ and $n_2$, you should assure that they have the same rate of convergence, in other words 
$$
\frac{n_1}{n_2} \xrightarrow{} c, \quad c \in (0, \infty). 
$$

Comment: VV thanks for your answer. However, the case I'm more interested in is precisely that of $n_1\neq n_2$, and it's also where you do the most 'hand-waving'. Could you please elaborate with more detail how you prove it?

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: VV, on the left-side, we don't seem to get the expression $\bar X_1 - \bar X_2$, but a function of $\bar X_1 + \bar X_2$. Also, the $n_i$ will not conform either, from what I can see...

Comment: I've added some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption $n_1\neq n_2$ implies that the limit of the CLT (if it applies) must be a **double limit** ($\lim_{n_1\to \infty ,n_2\to \infty } \cdots$). (Recall that this is no the same as the **iterated limits** $\lim_{n_1\to \infty}\lim_{n_2\to \infty } \cdots$ and $\lim_{n_2\to \infty}\lim_{n_1\to \infty } \cdots$ , [see eg](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/double-limits-and-iterated-limits-of-double-sequences-of-rea)).

To assert the validity of the CLT for the double limit seems not trivial.

The paper "[Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Asymptotic Standard
Normality of the Two Sample Pivot](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1612/1612.01668.pdf)" (Majumdar, Majumdar - 2010) mentions a result from the book "Mukhopadhyay, N. (2000) Probability and Statistical Inference" which states that , for any two sequences of iid random variables with finite variances, and independent of each other:

$$ \frac{\overline X_1 -\overline X_2 - (\mu_1 - \mu_2)  }{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}} \tag{1}$$

converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ along any line $n_1/n_2 = \delta \in (0,\infty)$ for $n_1,n_2 \to \infty$. Notice that still this leaves open the the convergence of double limit.

Comment: Thanks for the info leon ;)